# kworker blocking port 80 after update

Tags: 12.04, server, nginx

After an update and reboot, my file server doesnt work as expected anymore - port 80 gets blocked right away by a process `kworker`, making it impossible for `nginx` to use it.

```
:~# ps aux | grep kworker
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/3:0]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/4:0]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/5:0]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/6:0]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/7:0]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:1]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/2:1]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/3:1]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/4:1]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/5:1]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/6:1]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/7:1]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:2]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:3]
root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:4]
root        81  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:5]
root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:6]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/u:7]
root       103  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:25   0:00 [kworker/3:2]
root       839  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:26   0:00 [kworker/2:2]
root      1526  0.0  0.0   9388   924 pts/0    S+   07:29   0:00 grep --color=auto kworker
```

-

```
:~# uname -r
3.2.0-49-generic
```

What could be the problem here? I need to solve it asap, since it's impossible to access the files over web at this point. Already tried a reboot, didnt help.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted the `ps` output in a wrong way - I tought the number represented the used port, instead it was the PID.

The NGINX problem had a different source (still strange), and this solved the problem:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```